# How to remove redundance in text attributes?

Tags: c#, attributes

Say I have a piece of code such as:

```
[MyAttribute("Long long text 1", "Some more long text 1")]
[MyAttribute("Long long text 2", "Some more long text 2")]
[MyAttribute("Long long text 3", "Some more long text 3")]
public class TestClass 
{
   [...]
}
```

Is there  a way to introduce consts to substitute the common substrings in these attributes (i.e. `Long long text` and `Some more long text` in this example) ? I understand this might not be possible in terms of actual 'const' but surely there must be another feature for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constants:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public const string SomeConstant = "Long long text 1";
}

[MyAttribute(SomeClass.SomeConstant)]
public class SomeOtherClass
{
}
```

You just have to reference them properly.